# Using custom date format

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this working script to sent mails with data from a Google sheet:

```
  function SendEmail() {
  let timestamp = 0
  let poid = 1
  let sku = 2
  let qty = 3
  let description = 4
  let licenseid = 5
  let itcost = 6
  let total = 7
  let company = 8
  let contact = 9
  let contactmail = 10
  let endusermail = 11
  let address = 12
  let country = 13
  let status = 14
  let suppliermail = 15
  let currency = 16
  let otherinfo = 17
  let brand = 18
  let comment = 19
  let cc = 20

  let emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("MAIL")

  let ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA")
  let sd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA2")

  let data = ws.getRange("A2:V" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues()
  let sData = sd.getRange("B2:J" + sd.getLastRow()).getValues()

  let sInfo = sData.map(function (r) { return r[0] })

  data = data.filter(function (r) { return r[14] == 'SENTNOW' })

  if (data.length) {

    let found = false

    data.forEach(function (row) {

      emailTemp.ts = row[timestamp].toLocaleString("da-DK")
      emailTemp.po = row[poid]
      emailTemp.co = row[contact]
      emailTemp.cm = row[company]
      emailTemp.ad = row[address]
      emailTemp.cu = row[country]
      emailTemp.cn = row[contactmail]
      emailTemp.sk = row[sku]
      emailTemp.de = row[description]
      emailTemp.qt = row[qty]
      emailTemp.it = (row[itcost]).toLocaleString("da-DK")
      emailTemp.to = (row[total]).toLocaleString("da-DK")
      emailTemp.ce = row[comment]
      emailTemp.cy = row[currency]
      emailTemp.eu = row[endusermail]
      emailTemp.li = row[licenseid]
      emailTemp.ot = row[otherinfo]

      let indexSupp = sInfo.indexOf(row[15])

      if (indexSupp > -1) {

        //only change status if supplierdata email is found
        found = true

        emailTemp.spname = sData[indexSupp][1]
        emailTemp.saddress1 = sData[indexSupp][2]
        emailTemp.saddress2 = sData[indexSupp][3]
        emailTemp.scountry = sData[indexSupp][4]
        emailTemp.sterms = sData[indexSupp][5]
        emailTemp.scurrency = sData[indexSupp][6]
        emailTemp.sothers = sData[indexSupp][7]
        emailTemp.vat = sData[indexSupp][8] * 100

        emailTemp.totvat = (row[total] * sData[indexSupp][8]).toLocaleString("da-DK")

        emailTemp.totandvat = (row[total] + (row[total] * sData[indexSupp][8])).toLocaleString("da-DK")

        let subjectLine = "Subject line # " + row[poid]

        let htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent()

        //only send email if supplierdata email is found

        try {

          GmailApp.sendEmail(
            row[suppliermail],
            subjectLine,
            "",
            { name: 'Name', htmlBody: htmlMessage, bcc: 'myemail@domain.com' })

        }

        catch (err) {

          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err)

        }

      }

    })

    if (found) {

      let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA")
        .getRange('O2:O')
        .createTextFinder('SENTNOW')
        .replaceAllWith('SENT')

    }

  }
}
```

Only problem is the date format emailTemp.ts = row[timestamp].toLocaleString("da-DK")

This give output date-format "11.2.2022 06.00.00" within the e-mail sent to the reciever.

What I wish is the date to be just "02/11/2022"

I tried emailTemp.ts = row[timestamp].toLocaleString("da-DK").getDisplayValue() but that was not working.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If  the question is only about date, provide [mcve] focusing only on date. Don't just dump all your code in the question.

Comment: Well, I was trying that method a few weeks ago in another question and I was told to share more details. But ok, I will learn...

Comment: More details about the issue. What does email have to do anything with this question? Are those 12 variables needed for us to see the issue? Minimal doesn't mean incomplete. Everything needed to see the issue should be in the question. And the code should be reproducible as well. But it shouldn't be a useless code dump. Debugging is a art. You could've thrown the useless code. Started from scratch with exactly 1 cell and added a bunch of `console.log()`s. Pay attention to [Mcve]

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to figure out your time zone but try this.

```
emailTemp.ts = Utilities.formatDate(row[timestamp],"GMT","dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Reference

- [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=en#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: I get: Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.

Comment: Then row[timestamp] is not a Date object.  And this should have thrown an error `row[timestamp].toLocaleString("da-DK")`

Comment: Yep, you were right in the first place. 

emailTemp.ts = Utilities.formatDate(row[timestamp],"GMT","dd/MM/yyyy");

It worked.